# What should I do with my own entity Framework dll inorder to use it with visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ado.net, entity-framework-6, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have written Entity framework provider for my database. I have compiled and have got the required .dll. Now what should I do with this dll inorder to use it with visual studio 2013?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: I changed settings in registry (DataServices and DataProviders). But still not able to see my driver in VS2013

Answer (score 0):

You would need to register your custom provider DLL either in the application’s configuration file (app.config or web.config) or using code-based configuration.

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="My.Invariant.Name" type="MyProvider.MyProviderServices, MyAssembly"  />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

or

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
   public MyConfiguration()
   {
      SetProviderServices("My.New.Provider", new MyProviderServices());
   }
}
```

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Rebuilding%20EF%20providers%20for%20EF6

Comment: Note if you just want the DLL to show up in the Visual Studio 2013's reference dialog, then you will need to create a registry entry:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306149